# Printing at scale using MapInfo?

Tags: mapinfo, printing, scale

Using MapInfo 12.5, I want to be able to print a property at a set scale - say 1:1000 or 1:5000.

What is the easiest way to do it?

I want to be able to show a Scale Bar so that the user can simply measure length on the property with the scale bar.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that you're using the 32-bit version of MapInfo.

First, in your Map Window, go to Map -> Create Scale Bar. Follow the prompts and select a position for the scale bar.  You have the options to add a cartographic scale and you can change the style.
[image]
[image]

Unfortunately, in MapInfo, you cannot have a scale bar outside the Map Window like you can in most other GIS programs.  So, it is embedded inside the map window like so:

[image]

The next step is to creaate a new Layout and load your map frame onto it. You can do this by pressing the F5 button, or by going to Window -> New Layout Window... or by pressing this button [image]

If you double click on the map window in your layout, you'll be presented with the option to change the Cartographic Scale:

[image]

Your layout will look something like this (you can add more details to your layout as you see fit).

[image]

I have also use a tool called **[LayScale](http://www.mapinfotools.com/index.php?option=com_sobi2&sobi2Task=sobi2Details&catid=7&sobi2Id=276&Itemid=53)** in the past which creates a bunch of graphical elements on the layout representing a scalebar.  It's not ideal because it isn't dynamic and you need to create a new one if you change the scale of the map.

Comment: With MapInfo Pro 15.2, you can add a scalebar to the layout designer window that can be positioned any where you want - also outside the map window.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - appreciate your help PolyGeo and Peter.